# Can't manage to use web.config and .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-config

I'm trying to redirect users to a specific page on error 404 (not found), but whatever I try, it does nothing.

I tried using `Web.config` with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/errorPages/PageNotFound.aspx" />
        </customErrors>
        <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I tried with `.htaccess` too, but my host is Windows-based and I was told to use `Web.config`.

Anyway, why is it not working both on localhost and on the host? My website is coded in `PHP`.

Comment: What are you running IIS or apache?

Comment: Then web.config is the correct file to be working in. Try changing `<customErrors mode="Off">` to `On`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is it 500ing or just not showing the custom page? Do you have access to the IIS manager?

Comment: I don't have access to the IIS manager and it shows the regular error, not redirecting anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85044/discussion-between-chris85-and-omer-aviv).

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, I changed the code to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="./index.php" responseMode="Redirect" />                
      </httpErrors>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```